# unpivot a map/list/tuples using scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, unpivot

I have something like this:

```
val m1 = Map(A -> List(("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f")))
```

I want the result to be :

```
(Map(A -> List("a","b")), Map(A -> List ("c","d")), Map(A -> List("e","f")))
```

could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want something like a `List[Map[String, (String, String)]]` in the end? The triple doesn't quite make sense, what's so special about "3" here? Furthermore: you've told what you *want*, but what exactly have you *tried*?

Comment: that could be the end format. i just need a way to "unpivot" it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to do, but here is a way to convert `m1` to the desired structure:

```
val m1 = Map("A" -> List(("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f")))
m1.toList.flatMap { case (key, tuple) =>
 tuple.map(v => Map(key -> List(v._1, v._2)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , that s what i need .